# Generalising the spin concept from quaternions to octonions, any leads?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, mathematics, complex-numbers

The spin operators have the same commutation structure as the quaternions.

Can we generalize the 3 spin operators to 7 spin-like operators that behave like the octonions?  I'm looking for something matrix-like that would have the same commutation and associative properties as [octonions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octonion).

Has anyone come across the development of this idea in the literature? I'd be interested to see what people have come up with.

Comment: Two sources that you have probably found already: the geometry of the octonions   Tevian Dray p166 and https://www.google.ie/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://arxiv.org/pdf/0805.3221v4&ved=0ahUKEwiTnoeN5frPAhXnJcAKHaBsDbcQFggmMAQ&usg=AFQjCNFRKTUkeHppfNMYiTykxMRPOVRrNw&sig2=RK1KHvK2wFKEYv6hByikTw.   Sorry for the links  my phone is rubbish at c & pasting. But you can google the first the second is  arxiv. Hope they pan out for ypu

Comment: Note that spin operators are associative, while octonions are non-associative.

Comment: CountTo10: Thanks for the leads.  I've come across Tevian Dray, and I've seen research that he's done around this topic, but not an exploration of this topic yet.  The paper is new to me, and so far the introduction looks interesting.

Comment: I got the text by Tevian Dray.  It's a pretty nice read, just the right level of abstraction.  Based on how nice the presentation is, I'm sure I'm going to read the whole text.

Comment: John Baez is in to these things: http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/octonions/

Comment: Maybe instead it would be easier for me to look at an abstract development of this idea using just the operators as defined by the commutation relations, and use the ladder operators.  I wonder if anyone has already done this development.

Answer (score 1):

In asking for "something matrix-like" that "behaves like the octonions," what you're looking for seems to be a matrix representation of the octonions. Unfortunately, there is no way to represent the octonions as ordinary matrices, since matrix multiplication is always associative while octonion multiplication is not. However, there are some modifications you can make to matrix algebras (e.g. changing the way that matrix multiplication works or giving the matrices themselves a kind of bra-ket structure) that will allow you to get the kind of group action that you want. For more, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96429/matrix-representation-of-octonions.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm hoping to find, some sort of generalization of the matrix concept that could include operators that have both the association rules as octonions, and also could have eigenvalues and eigenvectors like spin-1/2 or spin-1 matrices.

Comment: @DavidElm Probably the closest thing would be the Zorn vector-matrix algebra, as discussed in the link in my answer.